# Joining Conference from SparkWeb : Using Openfire Server

Tags: apache-spark, openfire

Information : I have openfire server setup with sparkweb client. I am using OpenLDAP for user profile setup.

Query : I am able to login into the SparkWeb and able to communicate one on one with another users, but when I try to create a conference and I provide the server details in 'Add Conference Server' popup, it is saying "Looking up conference service.." And the popup stays there forever.

As per the openfire, in Group Chat service under Group Chat Settings the "Group chat service name" defaults to "conference" and from what I have read from other forums and posts, the server name should be "conference.ANY_NAME"  or "ANY_NAME@conference.DOMAIN_NAME". (*CAPS are variables)

But with none of the above 2, I am able to connect.

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Thanks,
-Dish

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very strange.

1. Add one Chat Room from Openfire server.
2. Now connect to this one in your SparkWeb. Server is = conference.DOMAIN_NAME
3. Now go back to Openfire - the chat room is marked as persistent.
4. Now add a new conference room, you will be able to add conference rooms form now onwards, just that if you are adding it from SparWeb, it will not be persistent, though the chat is archived.

Thanks.